# How to screenshot my android studio code in a class

Tags: android-studio

I am making a coursework in android studio. To showcase my job, I need to take picture of a class and including it in the word format. But I do not know how to take a screenshot of a class.

If I take a screenshot, my whole class is not captured as it does not fit to the screen. But, I need to take whole class.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Operating System you're using, there should be a PrintScreen key on your keyboard that would enable you to capture a picture of the class you're looking for. From there, you can paste it to the document you want to share it on and then proceed to crop it down to your specified image choice.

Comment: I want to take the whole class. But, if I take a screenshot, my whole class can not be pictured